# Laravel 5.1 GMAIL SMTP in mail.php

Tags: php, laravel

I am putting gmail smtp in mail.php file but after setting up this in mail.php, website front end and backend images stops showing. i really do not know what is the connection between this to mail.php.

Plz suggest me something on this.

return [

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
| sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
| your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
|
| Supported: "smtp", "mail", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "ses", "log"
|
*/

'driver' => 'smtp',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
| applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
| the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
|
*/

'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Port
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
| users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
| stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
|
*/

'port' => '587',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global "From" Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
| the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
| used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
|
*/

'from' => ['address' => 'c***@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Bigfyda'],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| E-Mail Encryption Protocol
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
| the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
| transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
|
*/

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', ''),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Username
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
| set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
| connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
|
*/

'username' => 'c****@gmail.com',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Password
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may set the password required by your SMTP server to send out
| messages from your application. This will be given to the server on
| connection so that the application will be able to send messages.
|
*/

'password' => '*****',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sendmail System Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
| the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
| been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
|
*/

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail "Pretend"
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When this option is enabled, e-mail will not actually be sent over the
| web and will instead be written to your application's logs files so
| you may inspect the message. This is great for local development.
|
*/

'pretend' => false,
```

];

Comment: the issues happens for only images?

Comment: yes. only images. all the images stopped loading on website when I use gmail smtp

Comment: is far i know it's not logical.Try revert mail.php and check.For image not showing,may be it's permission issue.

Comment: Thanx for ur concern. I checked all possible ways. still no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx all for your time.

I found my answer here....https://support.google.com/a/answer/3299041

I had to setup Image Proxy URL.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error message? Check the Requests with your developer console in the Network Tab. And check your laravel.log in storage/logs/laravel.log. What would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail's SMTP port is 465.
Try this one and maybe it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last comma:

```
'pretend' => false,
```

become

```
'pretend' => false
```